# Plot column every time a macro is selected

Tags: excel, vba

I need help to plot a column every time I selected. I have a spreadsheet with 30 columns but each column needs to plot individually for QA proposes. I created a macro when I can plot 4 columns at the time  but I think is is more efficient if every time I select a column I'm able to graph it individually.

thank you

I created a macro when I can plot 4 columns at the time  but I think is is more efficient if every time I select a column I'm able to graph it individually.

```
Sub AddChartsfirstset()
Dim i As Integer 'rows
Dim j As Integer 'columns


For j = 5 To 10
With ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
.ChartType = xlLine
.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    With .SeriesCollection(1)
    .XValues = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & _
    Range(Cells(12, 2), Cells(i, 2)).Address
    .Name = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & _
    Cells(10, j).Address
    .Values = "=" & ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & _
    Range(Cells(12, j), Cells(i, j)).Address
    End With
   ' .HasLegend = False
    End With
    Next j
  End Sub
```

'updated from this video on youtube:
'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_p8hltGY4s

Comment: Questions without code tend to get closed/downvoted here, so if you have existing code it's a good idea to include it in your question.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I copied my code

Comment: What does "select a column" look like exactly?  How would that process work - you select a cell in the (Y-axis data?) column and a new plot get created on clicking a button?  Does it replace any previous plot?   It's not clear exactly what workflow you want to set up...

Answer (score 0):

Look at the BeforeDoubleClick event.

https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/beforedoubleclick-event.html

Right click your tab name and click 'VIew Code' then copy/paste the code below.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, cancel As Boolean)
    
    Range("A1:B11").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet4!$A$1:$B$11")
    
'    Range("C1:C11,A1:A11").Select
'    Range("A11").Activate
'    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select
'    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet4!$C$1:$C$11,Sheet4!$A$1:$A$11")
'
'    Range("D1:D11,A1:A11").Select
'    Range("A11").Activate
'    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select
'    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet4!$D$1:$D$11,Sheet4!$A$1:$A$11")
'
'    Range("E1:E11,A1:A11").Select
'    Range("A11").Activate
'    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select
'    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet4!$E$1:$E$11,Sheet4!$A$1:$A$11")


End Sub
```

Also, copy/paste the data set below into cells A1:D11

```
              A           B           C           D
1   36.32286129 69.62445124 33.00718806 19.69686932
2   40.9299682  57.17523815 69.58784313 30.22291334
3   27.23734184 90.15533791 6.417345108 59.57592167
4   51.22043276 20.89789995 93.63828013 17.81731146
5   90.15903451 30.28320171 80.32835328 52.77214333
6   47.74961841 47.33797693 28.91756546 36.69461665
7   78.99597268 4.637482833 65.94320578 62.82294746
8   94.31050614 44.98751273 50.68768139 70.65617341
9   46.85657245 72.2629677  34.6163525  34.74623492
10  41.15528408 47.92624953 15.54198376 14.15547836
```

Double-click cell B1 and you will see this.

[image]

You can easily record a few Macros to do this!

'copied the code and only changed ("Sheet4!$A$1:$B$11") TO '("Sheet1!$A$1:$B$11")

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)

```
Range("A1:B11").Select
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$A$1:$B$11")


Range("C1:C11,A1:A11").Select
Range("A11").Activate
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$C$1:$C$11,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$11")

Range("D1:D11,A1:A11").Select
Range("A11").Activate
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$D$1:$D$11,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$11")

Range("E1:E11,A1:A11").Select
Range("A11").Activate
ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(227, xlLine).Select
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Sheet1!$E$1:$E$11,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$11")
```

End Sub

Comment: I don’t think I explain myself correctly. Can I hover over a column and plot it? I think is better for the end user to plot each column individually than plot sections (4 plots at the time)

Comment: I don't think it works quite like that! I just updated my original post. Follow the steps I described and you will see how it actually works.

Comment: thank you, it worked, every time I double click it, plot the 4 columns... however, how can I plot only one column each time. I want to double click on  column B and plot it, then close  plot B and double click on Column C plot it and Close

Comment: The code I shared plots 1 column, not 4 columns. You must have changed the code. The idea is to double-click one cell and fire a small VBA script, then doable-click another cell, and fire another small VBA script. Google it, and you will see.

Comment: Thank you, I will double check, the only thing I changed was sheet4 to sheet1

Comment: 4 plots stack on top of each other instead of plot the columns individually.

Comment: That's a totally different question. You need to recreate your question and repost again.